# OpenERP custom numbering

Tags: odoo

How to make a custom numbering fields in custom modules?

I need to associate a custom numbering with custom object field.

Comment: Would you please explain in clear and detail way?

Comment: Don you mean Sequences (as in Coonfiguration » Sequences & Identifiers » Sequences) ?

Comment: Administration -> Customization -> Numbering -> Here is list of integrated numerators. I create a custom numbering and specify a name,code,prefix - %(y)s/%(month)s. I also add a code numbering in Codes Numberings. Where can I specify a particular field to insert numbering in custom object? If possible...

Comment: Yes, I mean Configuration > Sequences & Identifiers > Sequences

Answer (score 1):

Add sequence for the model and in the defaults for the model define like this:

```
'name': lambda obj, cr, uid, context: obj.pool.get('ir.sequence').get(cr, uid, 'model.name'),
```